# create update query using stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have created stored procedure in oracle. But I want to run this procedure in mysql how can I create for loop in mysql .I do not have any idea about for loop in mysql.

```
Create table student
  (
    Id number,
    Batch varchar2(2),
    Batch_roll_no number 
  )

Create or replace procedure assign_roll_no
Is
 V_roll_no number; 
Begin
For c1 in (select distinct batch from student order by 1)
Loop
Select nvl(Max(batch_roll_no+1),1)
Into v_roll_no
From student
 where batch = c1.batch;
  For c2 in ( select id from batch where batch_roll_no is null and batch= c1.batch
 Order by 1)
 Loop
Update student
set batch_roll_no=v_roll_no
Where id=c2.id
And batch= c1.batch;
V_roll_no:=v_roll_no + 1;
End loop;
End loop;
End;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this link. It gives simple examples for your doubt. In case, you don't understand the content of the link. Get back to this thread with your doubts.

[Loops in MySQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-loop.aspx)

As far as the answer is concerned, I hope the following gives Pravin a clear picture of the scenario that you're looking at.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE loop_test() 
BEGIN  
WHILE c2 in (select id from batch where batch_roll_no is null and batch= c1.batch Order by 1)
DO  
Update student  
SET batch_roll_no=v_roll_no  
WHERE id=c2.id AND batch= c1.batch;  
V_roll_no:=v_roll_no + 1;  
END WHILE;  
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you @Joel for the suggestion. I have made necessary changes to the answer.

Comment: And then you get +1 from me because of that :) also, I've edited your answer to format code. In the future, consider using 4 spaces to indent your code, it will indicate S.O. to highlight the code automatically. See the pretty colors?